# How do I change a specific mat-tab-label background color

Tags: angular-material, angular9

I am looking for a way to change the background for a specific mat label.

For example I want to change the background color for content 1

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First" class="test">Content 1</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second">Content 2</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third">Content 3</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Material uses [themes](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming), and uses 'primary' 'accent' and 'warn' as theme colour values.  [Material Tab examples](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples#tab-group-theme)

Answer (score -1):

One way to change background-color(It can be any style), is to use

```
::ng-deep
```

Example:

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-label {
  background-color: red;
}
```

What ::ng-deep does is, it disables View Encapsulation for the specified component.